# How to pass context of calling activity to the called activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-context

Hello all actually i have an activity where i am using recyclerview to show all movies list with a button to upvote a movie on each movie item, now when a user clicks on any any movie item i opens detailsactivity where i am showing details about that movie which user has clicked, this detailsactivity also has a button to upvote this movie. Now the problem i am facing is suppose user didn't upvoted the movie in the recyclerview list but goes inside in detailsactivity and then there he upvoted the movie now when he presses back button i have to show this movie upvoted in my recyclerview.

Now i can solve my problem in two ways.

1. Using onActivityResult
    But this method show some latency because when click back button now in the caller activity i need to call notifyitemchanged() of my recyclerview adapter which takes some time. nearly 500msecs.
2. Storing Context in My Application class
    till now this thing working fine for me and in this there is no lag.

But i read a post on SO where a user wrote not to save context of an activity because an activity can gets destroyed. My whole App is in Portrait mode so i don't think there are much chances of getting my context destroyed accidently.

So any one of you can you please enlighten me is my second approach is right or not. It would be really helpful for me.

Thank You.

Comment: Try to use fragments instead activites

Comment: yeah i thought so, but i was just wondering how to solve this problem correctly using activities.

Comment: Where do you store your films items?

Comment: In the activity itself.

Comment: So, when user restarts your app, he will not see that he upvoted some film before?

Comment: no he will not.

Comment: actually the point is not about data because i can store it in shared preferences if i want. I just wan to ask how can i call notifyItemchanged() of movieslistactivity inside detailsactivity so that there wont be any lag, that' why i need context of movieslistactivity inside detailsactivity.

Comment: hm, without notifydatasetchanged you can't update your recyclerview, if some changes was on other widgets

Answer (score 3):

> How to pass context of calling activity to the called activity?

You can't.

> Now i can solve my problem in two ways

There are more ways than that, such as:

- Use an event bus (e.g., greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, RxJava/RxAndroid-based buses) when the user upvotes a movie, to let other interested parties know about the upvote. For example, your background thread that saves the upvote status might raise an event once the status has been persisted somewhere.
- Have the activity with the `RecyclerView` realize "hey, I launched a detail activity for Movie X, and I'm coming back to the foreground, so let's update the up-vote status for Movie X based upon our data model cache, since it may have changed", and do that work in `onResume()`.
- Since you wrote "actually the point is not about data because i can store it in shared preferences if i want", and though `SharedPreferences` would be a bizarre choice of data store, you could have the activity with the `RecyclerView` call `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` on the `SharedPreferences`, to find out when the up-vote status changes.
- Wrap your data store in a `ContentProvider`, and use a `ContentObserver` in the activity with a `RecyclerView`, to see when the data changes.

> Using onActivityResult But this method show some latency because when click back button now in the caller activity i need to call notifyitemchanged() of my recyclerview adapter which takes some time. nearly 500msecs.

Any solution will involve updating the `RecyclerView`, by definition. You would need to identify where this time is coming from.

> My whole App is in Portrait mode so i don't think there are much chances of getting my context destroyed accidently.

It will get destroyed on any configuration change, by default, which is much more than just an orientation change. Also, if the user leaves your app when the detail activity is in the foreground, you may have problems when the user returns to your app, if your process was terminated in the meantime.

> So any one of you can you please enlighten me is my second approach is right or not.

It is generally frowned upon (e.g., increased likelihood of memory leaks).

Comment: Can you please explain second point ??   "Have the activity with the RecyclerView realize "hey, I launched a detail activity for Movie X, and I'm coming back to the foreground, so let's update the up-vote status for Movie X based upon our data model cache, since it may have changed", and do that work in onResume()"

Comment: Also can you please tell me one thing where is rxjava better than a normal broadcast receiver ??

Comment: @PrakashKumar: "where is rxjava better than a normal broadcast receiver ?" -- that's out of scope for this answer. "Can you please explain second point ?" -- somewhere, you have a data model, with movies, upvote status, etc. Your `RecyclerView` activity has access to this data model. That activity also knows that it launched a detail activity for a certain movie within that data model, and that the detail activity will update that data model if the user changes the upvote status. So, in `onResume()`, just grab the upvote status for that movie and update its associated `RecyclerView` item.

Comment: i guess i cannot acheive this using Rx because i have searched everywhere i read articles on rxjava for reactive purpose but noone tells about how to use rxjava to send events from one activity to the other one. Can you please tell me how can i do that using rx or if you are busy then please suggest me any good tutorial so that i can do that using rx.